# TypeError: gradientDesc() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Tags: python, scipy

Trying to implement Logistic Regression in Python:

Below is the Cost Function:

```
def costFunction(theta_array):
   m = len(X1)
   theta_matrix = np.transpose(np.mat(theta_array))

   H_x = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X_matrix * theta_matrix))
   J_theta = ((sum(np.multiply((-Y_matrix), np.log(H_x)) - np.multiply((1 - Y_matrix), np.log(1 - H_x)))) / m )[0, 0]

   return J_theta
```

Below is the Gradient Function:

```
def gradientDesc(theta_tuple):
   theta_matrix = np.transpose(np.mat(theta_tuple))

   H_x = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X_matrix * theta_matrix))
   G_theta0 = (sum(np.multiply(H_x - Y_matrix, X_matrix[:, 0])) / m)[0, 0]
   G_theta1 = (sum(np.multiply(H_x - Y_matrix, X_matrix[:, 1])) / m)[0, 0]
   G_theta2 = (sum(np.multiply(H_x - Y_matrix, X_matrix[:, 2])) / m)[0, 0]


   return np.array((G_theta0, G_theta1, G_theta2))
```

Then I run the optimize.fmin_bfgs function, as below:

```
initial_theta = np.zeros((3, 1))
theta_tuple = (0, 0, 0)

theta_optimize = op.fmin_bfgs(costFunction, initial_theta, gradientDesc, args = (theta_tuple))
```

Then I got the error below:

```
**TypeError: gradientDesc() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)**
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix?   :)     Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the `args` parameter you should specify a single-item tuple (also known as a [singleton](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)) with a comma instead; otherwise the parentheses do nothing more than grouping the expression.

Change:

```
theta_optimize = op.fmin_bfgs(costFunction, initial_theta, gradientDesc, args = (theta_tuple))
```

to:

```
theta_optimize = op.fmin_bfgs(costFunction, initial_theta, gradientDesc, args = (theta_tuple,))
```

Also, your `gradientDesc` should accept an additional parameter per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html).

Change:

```
def gradientDesc(theta_tuple):
```

to:

```
def gradientDesc(x, theta_tuple):
```

Comment: Now, there's still error. This time it is TypeError: gradientDesc() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given),   instead of (4 given)          :(